# How do I get rid of the "{}" in my windows output? (Python / SQLite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating a flashcard game to ask CompSci questions.

I'm trying to retrieve a random "CardFront" which acts as a varchar stored in an SQLite3 DB table, and output that result to a messagebox to "Prompt" the user with the question.

Only problem I can't seem to figure out is why it is returning with squiggly brackets around the statement?

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

def retrieve_random_cardfront():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('flashcards.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT CardFront FROM FLASHCARDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo(title='Test', message=result[0])
```

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPYqW.png)

Comment: It looks like the message is a set. Try `message = ', '.join(result[0]); messagebox.showinfo(title='Test', message=message)`.

Comment: How are you populating the database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this as a fix, but what is happening is unclear here. Maybe check into the `__repr__` of the result object ?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox

def retrieve_random_cardfront():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('flashcards.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT CardFront FROM FLASHCARDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo(title='Test', message=str(result[0]).strip('{').strip('}'))
```

Comment: If the data that is returned from the database itself has '{' or '}', those will be deleted, showing a false representation of what was in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement something like this in order to remove that "{}". But since I'm not aware of using SQLite, I could give you a more precise answer.

```
data = "{Data}"
data = data.replace(data[0], "")
data = data.replace(data[-1], "")
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

tkinter will add curly braces when it expects a string but you pass a list. The proper solution is to convert your list to a string before using it with a widget. The following example shows once possible way:

```
message = ",".join(result[0])
messagebox.showinfo(title='Test', message=message)
```